# Python list of tuples manipulation

Tags: python, list, tuples

I'm doing something in Python and I've a list of tuples that looks like this:

```
list = [(id1, name1), (id2, name2), (id3, name3), (id4, name4)]
```

and I want to make it look like this:

```
list = [(id1, name1, id2, name2), (id3, name3, id4, name4)]
```

I don't know what function to use to merge 2 tuples in the list.

Comment: Is there an even number of `id`s?

Comment: yes, there 8 tuples in the list.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this:

```
In [10]: l = [(1, "a"), (2, "b"), (3, "c"), (4, "d")]

In [11]: new_list = [l[i*2] + l[i*2+1] for i in xrange(len(l) / 2)]

In [12]: new_list
Out[12]: [(1, 'a', 2, 'b'), (3, 'c', 4, 'd')]
```

And another option:

```
In [16]: new_list = [a + b for a,b in zip(l[::2], l[1::2])]

In [17]: new_list
Out[17]: [(1, 'a', 2, 'b'), (3, 'c', 4, 'd')]
```

Comment: Hey! Copycat...</joking>

Answer (score 1):

`itertools` is your friend:

```
from itertools import chain, zip_longest

# from itertools recipes
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

We start with the list of tuples

```
>>> old_list = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (7,8)]
```

Then we use `chain.from_iterable` to chain all the elements from all tuples together, and group them in sets of 4:

```
>>> list(grouper(chain.from_iterable(old_list), 4))
[(1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 6, 7, 8)]
```

If you have an odd number of tuples, the remaining values will be `None`, unless you specify a different value in the `fillvalue` parameter:

```
>>> ls.append((9, 10))
>>> list(grouper(chain.from_iterable(ls), 4, fillvalue="missing"))
[(1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 6, 7, 8), (9, 10, 'missing', 'missing')]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `id` list is always even as you say, then you can make use of `zip()` and Python's slice notation:

```
>>> ids = [('id1', 'name1'), ('id2', 'name2'), ('id3', 'name3'), ('id4', 'name4')]
>>> ids = [i + j for i, j in zip(ids[0::2], ids[1::2])]
>>> ids
[('id1', 'name1', 'id2', 'name2'), ('id3', 'name3', 'id4', 'name4')]
>>>
```

The main part of this soultion is making use of Pythons unique slice notation. The slice notation `[start::step]` basically means start at `start` and only grab the items at every `step` index. So `ids[0::2]` yields `[('id1', 'name1', 'id2', 'name2')]` and `ids[1::2]` yields `[('id3', 'name3', 'id4', 'name4')]`.